# From iPhone 5 to iPhone 6 and Plus, everything written in codes, solution proposed

Tags: ios, iphone-5, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I have a project which is supported for iPhone 5 and 4.
I wrote everything in code,i.e. no xibs or storyboards.
For example, a custom cell, there is a imageView like:

```
self.thumbnailImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 180)];
```

In order to support 6 and plus, I want to scale the frame to fit 6 and plus screen, so I did something like:

```
self.thumbnailImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CAL(10), CAL(10), CAL(300), CAL(180))];
```

Where CAL is a Marco:

```
#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH <= 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)


#define CAL(x) (IS_IPHONE_5_OR_LESS? x : RECAL(x) )
#define RECAL(x) (IS_IPHONE_6?RECAL_6(x):RECAL_6P(x))
#define RECAL_6(x) (x*375.0/320)
#define RECAL_6P(x) (x*414.0/320)
```

It checks if the device is 5/less or 6/plus and adjust the value accordingly.

I am not sure if this solution is feasible. I tried in simulator and it seemed working fine. Ang suggestions?

I also tried autoresizingMask, but it seems this method needs to change quite a lot of things and it is more complex.

Comment: Good luck with the if else ladders ahead :)

Comment: What do you mean? Would it cause efficiency problem?

Comment: It means you have to manage a lot of layout conditions

Comment: I would suggest you bite the bullet and convert to storyboards - then she another new screen size arrives you won't have to do anything